# How to get CC and BCC email addresses from Gmail Contextual Gadget

Tags: gmail, gmail-contextual-gadgets

We are using Gmail Contextual Gadgets in our organization.While using the gadget I am able to fetch sender email address and body, subject of the mail but unable to get the CC and BCC email Ids.

Can some one help on this issue.

this my following snippet:-

```
 matches = google.contentmatch.getContentMatches();
  for (var match in matches) {
        for (var key in matches[match]) {
          if( key =="sender_email")
            {
            email_id =matches[match][key];
          }
         if(key == 'recipient_to_email')
           {                        
            from_email  =matches[match][key];
            }
          if(key == 'recipient_cc_email')
           {                        
            cc_emails  =matches[match][key];
           }
         if(key == "email_body")
            {
            email_body =matches[match][key];                    
            }
          if(key == "subject")
            {
            subject =matches[match][key];                   
            }
          if(key == 'message_id')
            {
             msg_id = matches[match][key];                      
            }
         }
    }
```

I am using the following Extractors of Google
google.com:SubjectExtractor
google.com:MessageIDExtractor
google.com:SenderEmailExtractor
google.com:RecipientToEmailExtractor
google.com:EmailBodyExtractor
google.com:RecipientCCEmailExtractor

Comment: I dont know gmail contextual gadget, but if it is about mails you received then you wont see the BCC fields. The purpose of BCC is that it is only known to the sender.

Comment: Thanks niese for ur quick reply.

Comment: Can some one help me in getting the CC email id from Gmail Contextual Gadget?

Answer (score 1):

Finally my issue has been resolve when I use

Extractor : google.com:RecipientCCEmailExtractor

and scope  : recipient_cc_email

To fetch the BCC email id there is no extractor and scope available in Gmail extrators.

or you can use
Extractor  : google.com:RecipientEmailExtractor
and scopes : recipient_email

Comment: Are you still using manifest.xml do describe your extractors or is it enought to specify your extractors from the console for Google Apps Marketplace SDK where you can specifiy all you extractors?

Comment: No, I am not using the manifest.xml, I configured all the required extractors in Google Apps Marketplace SDK only. All my issues have been resolved!

Comment: So are you saying that there is NO way to extract the Bcc address?

Of course, I realize you can't see the Bcc address unless you are the sending who put the Bcc address on the message... but can you extract the Bcc address from messages in your sent items (for example)?